# Request not coming to the back-end

Tags: angular, typescript

When I test in postman ,all are working nicely,but when I testing from front-end, request not going to the back-end

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VerifyCodeService {
  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth' ;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

  check_verification(verify){
  // console.log(verify);
    return this.http.put(this.baseURL+`/check_verification`, verify);  
  }
}
```

Comment: You should also write out how you gonna use that method: what is "verify" in this case? From where you use it, and how? Are you consuming the Promise that http.put() returns, or just seamlessly launching that method?

Comment: I'm passing user_id and verifycode as a object(verify) to this service , just launching that method

Comment: Do you use .then() or async/await in the returned promise to check the result that the backend should return? Did you try with a "post" request?

Comment: I tried "post", but not working

Comment: Until unless you not subscribe to the service method ```http``` call not get placed. http works on observables and return observable internally so you have to subscribe to get execute.

Comment: @SantoshShinde tried this, but notworking

Comment: can you add you component code where you are calling ```check_verification()``` method.

Comment: @SantoshShinde I use suscribe Its working now

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for an Angular's HTTP response, shouldn't be a plain value, but rather, a key-pair object.

Try the following approach:

```
  check_verification(verify){
    return this.http.put(this.baseURL+`/check_verification`, {user_id: verify});  
  }
```

Anyways, don't forget to listen to the result of the backend (if it succeeds) using .`then()` or `async/await`.

Comment: I tried this, but not working.Anyway thanks for the help